# I am making project using servlet and jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

I have written this and its working properly and data is saved in database but no statement is get executed after execute() statement. Please help me...

public static String addNewMember(MemberRegister member){
        String message=null;
    try
    {

```
        if(!(IsUserValid(member.getEmail()))){
            conn=getConnection();
            System.out.println("user not exist");
            callStmt = conn.prepareCall("{call insertMember(?,?,?)}");
            callStmt.setString(1, member.getCompanyName());
            callStmt.setString(2, member.getEmail());
            callStmt.setString(3, member.getPassword());

            //register the OUT parameter before calling the stored procedure
            System.out.println(callStmt.execute());

            //read the OUT parameter now
            message="Record added successfully";
         }
        else{
            message="Record already exists";
        }
}
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            if(callStmt != null)
                callStmt.close();
            if(conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Hello "+message);
    return message;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try using executeUpdate() method (because INSERT is a DML) which is inherited from PreparedStatement . It will return an int value and check the returned int value to see if it's executed or not.

executeUpdate() returns no. of rows affected.

If you want i can send a modified code.